# ArcPy "listElements" error reported

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, python-script-tool, zoom, indexerror

I'm writing a script to convert a CAD polygon feature in a shapefile, calculate area(ha) in a new field and zoom to it in a 25.000 scale.

```
import os, arcpy, sys
from arcpy import env 

#PAR�METROS DA TOOLBOX
#inputFolder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
fc = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
outputFolder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

#DEFINE O AMBIENTE DE TRABALHO
arcpy.env.workspace = outputFolder 
#Ws=arcpy.env.workspace
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
df = aprx.listMaps("Layers")[0]
sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(r"S:\UPAR\06_ARCGIS_DEMANDAS\02_SHAPES_GEOPORTAL\SIRGAS 2000 UTM Zone 23S.prj")
df.spatialReference = sr
LyrName = 'Poligonal_projeto'
newfile = os.path.join(outputFolder,"Poligonal_projeto.shp")
arcpy.AddMessage(newfile)
path = outputFolder

#CRIA A FUN��O
def INCAD(fc, outputFolder):

    # Step through each dataset in the list
    for file in fc:

        if arcpy.Exists(outputFolder):
            arcpy.Delete_management("Poligonal_projeto.shp")
            arcpy.Delete_management("Poligonal_projeto.lyr")

        # Select only the Polygon features on the drawing layer Poligonal_projeto
        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc + "/Polygon", LyrName, "\"Layer\" = 'Poligonal_projeto'")

        # Execute SaveToLayerFile
        arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management(LyrName,os.path.join(outputFolder, LyrName + ".lyr"))
        arcpy.FeatureClassToShapefile_conversion(Input_Features="Poligonal_projeto", Output_Folder=outputFolder)

        # verifificar geometria
        desc = arcpy.Describe(newfile)
        arcpy.AddMessage("desc OK")
        geometria = desc.shapeType
        if geometria == 'Polygon':

            # calcula área (hectare)
            fieldName = "AREA_HA"
            expr ='!shape.area@hectares!'
            arcpy.management.AddField(newfile,"AREA_HA","DOUBLE") and arcpy.CalculateField_management(newfile,fieldName,expr,'PYTHON')
            arcpy.AddMessage("ÁREA OK")

            # Adiciona a camada "Poligonal_projeto" como primeira camada no data frame
            filepath = path + '\\' + "Poligonal_projeto.shp"
            arcpy.AddMessage(filepath)
            addLayer = df.addDataFromPath(newfile)

            # Zoom para camada "Poligonal_projeto" na escala 1:25.000
            lyr = df.listLayers("Poligonal_projeto")[0]
            arcpy.AddMessage(lyr)
            lyt = aprx.listLayouts("MAP_CONSULT_AUTOMATIZACAO")[0]
            arcpy.AddMessage(lyt)
            mf = lyt.listElements('TEXT_ELEMENT', 'Poligonal_projeto')[0]
            arcpy.AddMessage(mf)
            mf.setExtent(mf.getLayerExtent(lyr))
            mf.scale = 25000

            # Label do campo "AREA_HA" com fonte de tamanho e cor personalizada
            #for layer in lyr():
                #if layer.name == "Poligonal_projeto":
                    #if layer.supports("LABELCLASSES"):
                        #for lblClass in lyr.labelClasses:
                            #lblClass.expression = "\"<CLR red = '150' green = '150' blue = '150'><FNT size = '12'>\" & [AREA_HA] & \"</FNT></CLR>\""
                            #layer.showLabels = True
            
        #arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
        #arcpy.RefreshTOC()
        #aprx.save()
        #del aprx, df, addLayer
        break

INCAD(fc, outputFolder)
```

---

> Failed script Script1...  Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "D:\ARCGIS\UPAR\SCRIPTS\IMPORT_CAD_Poligonal_Projeto_PY3.py", line 79,
> in 
> INCAD(fc, outputFolder)   File "D:\ARCGIS\UPAR\SCRIPTS\IMPORT_CAD_Poligonal_Projeto_PY3.py", line 60,
> in INCAD
> mf = lyt.listElements('TEXT_ELEMENT', 'Poligonal_projeto')[0] IndexError: list index out of range  Failed to execute (Script1).

MY MAPFRAME IS "Layers" and my layout is "MAP_CONSULT_AUTOMATIZACAO"

---

I insert this line right after the 'lyt' variable created - arcpy.AddMessage(lyt.listElements('mapframe_element'))

The result is appearing like memory address: <MappingLayerObject object at 0x0000027AB2F9F170> [<MappingMapFrameObject object at 0x0000027AB1B59F90>, <MappingMapFrameObject object at 0x0000027AB1B59570>] Failed script Script1...

The main error presented now is: mf = lyt.listElements('TEXT_ELEMENT', 'Poligonal_projeto')[0] IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 1):

You reported an error of:

> ERROR: mf = lyt.listElements('mapframe_element',
> 'Poligonal_projeto')[0] IndexError: list index out of range

The Layout object that you are working with appears not to have a map frame named “Poligonal_projeto” and returns an empty list when you look for it. I think you should check the spelling and/or capitalization of the one you are trying to create a MapFrame object for.

To see the names of any map frames in your layout you could include this line immediately before the line where you try looking for one named “Poligonal_projeto”:

```
arcpy.AddMessage(lyt.listElements('mapframe_element'))
```

Comment: Sorry, I'll write the entire script, cause I mentioned "Poligonal_projeto" previously.

Comment: Please only present a [code snippet](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) that can be run to show what you’ve tried and where you’re stuck. Just mentioning that string in your code is not enough if your ArcGIS Project does not have a map frame of that exact name.